# What might be causing this error message during the execution of my SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have created an SSIS package in SSMS using the Import Data Wizard.

The package imports a table from the database of a linked server and creates a copy on the main database. The SSMS wizard executed all the steps correctly and during one of the steps, I saved the settings as an SSIS package in the File System.

I then created a SQL Server Agent job to execute the package on a daily basis. The  job failed to execute with the following error message:

> (Import Data into PickUp Table).,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0
>   06/20/2018 17:18:00,PickUp Table,Error,2,XXXX\XXXXXX,PickUp Table,Import Data into PickUp Table,,Executed as user: XXXXXX\sql_bisvcs. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  5:18:01 PM
>   Error: 2018-06-20 17:18:01.16
>   Code: 0xC0010018
>   Source: PickUp
>   Description: Error loading value "
>   End
>   Error
>   Could not load package "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\projects\PickUp\PickUp.dtsx" because of error 0xC0010014.  Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.".
>   This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   Source: PickUp
>   Started:  5:18:01 PM  Finished: 5:18:01 PM  Elapsed:  0.157 seconds.
>   The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

I tried to open the package in SSDT, but it failed giving me the same error messages as mentioned above.

What might be causing this error?

Comment: Open the dtsx as if it were a text file and validate it's XML structure, make sure it doesn't end abruptly. Other than that, we will need to see the full content to review it. You can create the package directly in SSIS as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the value of `Run64BitRuntime` debug parameter and try different value `True` or `False`.
Depending of your environment, some DLL of third party software can be in conflict.

Also, if your SQL Server instance is on an other server than the computer on wich you want to run the job, you may not be able to execute the package with features you have not installed on this machine.
  SSDT, Connector to each remote database / file etc..

Have a look at your SSDT version, if the package is generated via SSMS, it can have a version wich is not recognize by your local machine.

Comment: Thanks. How do I look for that Run64BitRuntime value?

Comment: It's an environment variable inside Visual studio. Change this value and run the package this is the same thing than call DTEXEC in 32 or 64bit.